# Android media recorder prepare failed

Tags: android, video-streaming, android-camera, android-mediarecorder

```
sock = new Socket();
sock.connect(new InetSocketAddress(addr, port), 2000);
if(!sock.isConnected()) return false;

file = ParcelFileDescriptor.fromSocket(sock);

camera = Camera.open();
if(camera == null) return false;
camera.unlock();

recorder = new MediaRecorder();
recorder.setCamera(camera);
recorder.setAudioSource(MediaRecorder.AudioSource.CAMCORDER);
recorder.setVideoSource(MediaRecorder.VideoSource.CAMERA);
recorder.setProfile(CamcorderProfile.get(CamcorderProfile.QUALITY_HIGH));
recorder.setOutputFile(file.getFileDescriptor());
recorder.setPreviewDisplay(preview.getHolder().getSurface());// SurfaceView preview

recorder.prepare();
```

---

Manifest:

```
uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"
uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE"
uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CAMERA"
uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECORD_AUDIO"
uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.camera"
```

I always get error `prepare failed: -1`.

This code is for android > 2.2, tested on Samsung Galaxy S2

Answer (score 0):

Remove the core -

```
recorder.setProfile(CamcorderProfile.get(CamcorderProfile.QUALITY_HIGH));
```

And set it -

```
recorder.setAudioSource(MediaRecorder.AudioSource.DEFAULT);
```